# What is the use case difference between GRE and GRETAP?

Tags: tunneling

What is the difference use case between GRE nad GRETAP? I understand that GRETAP is layer 2"Ethernet" tunnel.

But when to use GRE and when to use GRETAP? Can you give me specific example for each use case?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://xyproblem.info/ : instead of pondering if Y1 (GRE) or Y2 (GRETAP) will solve your problem X, at least tell what is the problem X to solve.